# how do I generate a list from a 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame' ? Current result is a TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv, typeerror

I created a pandas.core.frame.DataFrame using pandas to work with a csv file. This csv file has a column with the names of businesses, a columns with the city of these businesses and more.

```
import pandas as pd

csv_data = pd.read_csv('cb_sample.csv')
```

I am interested in creating a list from the csv_data of all the business names that are located in New York. I attempted the code below:

```
names = [obj['city'] for obj in csv_data if obj['city'] == 'New York']
print(names)
```

It resulted in a TypeError: string indices must be integers.

I need to create a list of the names so I can work with them for a simple flask project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need an explicit loop here, and it is what causes the error.

`for x in y` where `y` is a dataframe iterates over the column names (much like `for k in dict` iterates over the keys).

Instead, just filter the rows by city, then use `tolist`:

```
names = obj[obj['city'] == 'New York']['names'].tolist()
```

Can also be done with `.loc`:

```
names = obj.loc[obj['city'] == 'New York', 'names'].tolist()
```